# FileProvider throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, eclipse, illegalargumentexception

I have designed an Activity(*MainActivity.java*) which can capture images on clicking **CaptureButton** and diplays all the captured images there itself on clicking **ShowFilesButton** in the form of ListView.
But my application is getting crashed on running it in Emulator/Android device as i am getting the following RunTimeError as shown in LogCat.

**Error Screenshot of Logcat**

[image: Error Screenshot of Logcat]
**android.support.v4.content.FileProvider** is also present in my Eclipse

[image: android.support.v4.content.FileProvider]

**Provider tag in AndroidManifest file**-I am not sure of what value to be provided in *authorities* attribute.

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.example.showinfo.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

**@xml/file_paths**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path android:path="images/" android:name="myimages" />
</paths>
```

**com.example.showinfo.MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listfiles=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listfiles);
        capturebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.captureimage);
        showfilesbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.showfiles);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        capturebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent,RCODE);
                }
            }
        });

showfilesbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                File rootfolder= getFilesDir();
                File folder=new File(rootfolder, "images");
                File[] files=folder.listFiles();
                String[] filenames={};
                for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
                    filenames[i]=files[i].getAbsolutePath();
                ArrayAdapter<String> a=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,filenames);
                listfiles.setAdapter(a);

            //Uri contentUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.showinfo.fileprovider", files[0].getAbsoluteFile());

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The authority is simply a String that identifies your file provider.

Per [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html):

> Set the android:authorities attribute to a URI authority based on a
>   domain you control; for example, if you control the domain
>   mydomain.com you should use the authority com.mydomain.fileprovider.

In your AndroidManifest.xml, per [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html):

> Set the android:exported attribute to false; the FileProvider does not
>   need to be public.

Your file_paths.xml should look like this (You do not need the XML namespace or *android:* preceding your attributes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path path="images/" name="myimages" />
</paths>
```

In your MainActivity.java - this should precede `startActivityForResult(intent,RCODE);`:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.showinfo.fileprovider", yourDirectoryOfFiles);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Your post is relatively old. Hopefully you figured things out...but maybe this will help someone else. :)